# Given two matrices A and B, what is the rank of AB?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

[image: Doesn't rank means number of non zero rows in a matrix?]

The solution in the book is, I guess , wrong because determinant of the matrix AB is not zero and so rank must be 2 but it explains to be 1.

Comment: I would get a different book. Any invertible square matrix has full rank, so $AB$ has rank $2$.

Comment: Guess I will have to change the book from library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think the rank of AB should be 2. AB can be reduced to the identity matrix, so it has two pivot columns and thus rank 2.

Comment: So the first part of logic explained in book is wrong?

Comment: I think so, yes.